# How can I get a list of diagonals in the form of a dictionary with the key representing indexes of the first item?

Tags: python

I'm building the game Othello and the board looks like this:

```
L= [['.','.','.','.'],
   ['.','B','W','.'],
   ['.','W','B','.'],
   ['.','.','.','.']]
```

a part of my logic revolves around a function that returns a dictionary with the values being lists of diagonals and the key a tuple the contains two numbers; the indexes for the first item in the list. so for example the left diagonals for the following board would look like this:

```
{(0, 1): ['.', '.'], (1, 3): ['.', 'B', '.'], (2, 3): ['.', '.'], (3, 3): ['.'], (0, 3): ['.', 'W', 'W', '.'], (0, 2): ['.', 'B', '.'], (0, 0): ['.']}
```

I did this using the following code

```
def get_Rightdiagonally_adjacent(Li,ir,ic):
     L = []
     for i in range(max(len(Li),len(Li[0]))):
     try:
         L.append(Li[ir+i][ic+i])
    except:
        return L
    return L

def get_Leftdiagonally_adjacent(Li,ir,ic):
    L = []
    for i in range(max(len(Li),len(Li[0]))):
        if ic - i < 0:
            return L
        try:
            L.append(Li[ir+i][ic-i])
        except:
            return L
    return L


def get_Leftdiagonals(M: "2D list") -> list:
    Ld = {}
    for i in range(1,len(M)):
        Ld[(i,len(M[0])-1)] = get_Leftdiagonally_adjacent(M,i,len(M[0])-1)
    for i in range(len(M[0])):
        Ld[0,i] = get_Leftdiagonally_adjacent(M,0,i)

    return Ld

def get_Rightdiagonals(M: "2D list") -> list:
    Ld = {}
    for i in range(len(M[0])):
        Ld[(0,i)] = get_Rightdiagonally_adjacent(M,0,i)
    for i in range(1,len(M)):
        Ld[(i,0)] = get_Rightdiagonally_adjacent(M,i,0)
    return Ld

get_Leftdiagonals(L)
```

What I am trying to do is implement a similar function that does the same thing only to the discs, the output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
 {(1,1):["B"],(1,2):['W','W'],(2,2):['B']}
```

Note how the tuples represent the indexes of the first item in the list with respect to the original board.I have failed miserably at this after trying for a couple of days, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do your dictionaries look like and what do you want them to look like. Also, is the expression `Ld[(1,0)]` correct in the second to last line?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I can't remove the spaces and change the keys of the dictionaries so that it works"?

Comment: for a board like this:                                                                                    ['.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', 'B', 'W', 'B']
['.', 'W', 'B', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.']                                                                                                The dictionaries look like this {(0, 1): [], (1, 3): ['B', 'B'], (2, 3): [], (3, 3): [], (0, 3): ['W', 'W'], (0, 2): ['B'], (0, 0): []}                                                                  However I need them to look like this {(1,3):['B','B'],(1,2):['W','W'],(1,1):['B']}

Comment: I can't remove the '.' from the lists and maintain the correct indexes for the discs

Comment: No i typed it wrong, it is supposed to be Ld[(i,0)]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Your posted code references a **self** object, but it's not inside a class.  We generally need code to fully reproduce the problem so that we can effectively develop solutions.  I think I see the algorithmic problem, but I shouldn't have to complete your design in order to test the problem.  See the [help documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the intro tour; we should be able to run your posted code and reproduce the problem from that alone.

Comment: I edited the question and code to make it more clear, thanks for pointing this out and sorry for my messiness. This is my first post

Comment: So you say you can't remove the empty strings because you need indices to match up. So what is your question? It doesn't seem like the question you asked can be answered given your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You say you can't remove the empty strings without messing up indices. One approach you could take is to store the offset along with each value, so the indices are preserved. For example:

```
def get_Rightdiagonally_discs(Li,ir,ic):
    # Get the unstripped diagonal
    L = get_Rightdiagonally_adjacent(Li, ir, ic)
    # Return pairs of the offset from ir/ic and value for locations with discs only
    return [(i, disc) for i, disc in enumerate(L) if disc != '.']
```

So for the original code with a right diagonal beginning at `(3,3)` with value `['.', 'W', 'W', '.']` this pairs with offsets, then strips `'.'`s, returning `[(1, 'W'), (2, 'W')]` which limits you to elements with discs and identifies their offsets so you have complete information on where they fall along the diagonal. Will that work?